# Aviary SDK for iOS: Present view controller on top of AFPhotoEditorController does not work well

Tags: ios, aviary

I am trying to present a view controller (say `photoEditedViewController`) on top of **`AFPhotoEditorController`** as,

```
- (void)photoEditor:(AFPhotoEditorController *)editor finishedWithImage:(UIImage *)image{
   PhotoEditedViewController* vc = [[PhotoEditedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoEditedViewController" bundle:nil];
   [editor presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then in **`PhotoEditedViewController.m`**

```
- (IBAction)cancel {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Once I am back to `AFPhotoEditorController`, the top navigation bar is unresponsive at all. I am unable to tap on any of the top navigation buttons.

I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same here, I'm having the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: i have similar issue but with a different path of execution

Answer (score 1):

I am the iOS Lead at Aviary. Once the user has finished in the editor by pressing the done or cancel buttons, the user will not able able to interact with any of the elements of the editor. This is because once the edit has been finished by the user, the SDK will begin performing any high-resolution edits that have been requested by the developer. You should dismiss the editor before presenting your new controller.